# How do i write an array of Young kids' ID - Java

Tags: java, arrays

i'm having trouble with my Homework, the assignment is that i need to write an array for adult and a kid, which needs to contain Birthday, country, fname, lname but the adult array also needs to contain a list of his children's ID and i have no clue how to do that
this is my Kid's array:

```
import java.util.*;
public class tYID {
    private String country;
    private String leom;
    private int ID;
    private tDate date;
    private String name;
    private String lname;
    public tYID(String country, String leom, int iD, tDate date, String name, String lname) {
        super();
        this.country = country;
        this.leom = leom;
        ID = iD;
        this.date = date;
        this.name = name;
        this.lname = lname;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    public String getLeom() {
        return leom;
    }
    public void setLeom(String leom) {
        this.leom = leom;
    }
    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }
    public void setID(int iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }
    public tDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(tDate date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }
    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }


}
```

this is my adult's array(without getters&setters&constructors yet):

```
import java.util.*;
public class tAdID {

    private String country2;
    private String leom2;
    private int ID2;
    private tDate date2;
    private String name2;
    private String lname2;



}
```

i need to add to the Adult's array a list of his Children's ID, how do i do that?

Comment: Do you know the max amount of kids an adult has?

Comment: No i don't.....

Comment: @דינדומחמודי Before you can create an array, you need to know this information - an array is a fixed length container of elements

Comment: An ArrayList would be the way to go, if your homework allows for that.

Comment: The only thing i know about the Children is that they must be below 18
and i guess i can identify them but the last name from the YID i presented in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D M's answer is good, but I think ArrayLists are better for this situation. ArrayLists allow for a dynamic sizing, so you don't have to set the size of the array or know the maximum number of kids.

You would have to call the below method for each child you wanted to add to the ArrayList. You would have to import java.util.ArrayList.

```
ArrayList children = new ArrayList();
public void addChild (tYID child) {
   children.add(child);
}
```

Or you could modify the code so it would take the ID's instead of the entire object.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i don't know how many children he has, i just know he has children and i need to add a List of their IDs to the adult's array

Comment: You don't need the number of children with this code, it just uses ArrayList instead of Array. You would just run this method whenever you wanted to add a child to the adult's child ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make an array of the kids inside the adult class.

```
private tYID[] kids;
```

If you really want *just* the ID, you could make an int array instead.

```
private int[] kidsID;
```

By the way, names like `country2` are unnecessary.  You can have variables named the same thing in different classes.  They won't interfere with each other.

Comment: Yeah i knew about the country, it was just was just for estatic purposes
and what do i write inside the array to get the IDs